# Javafx CheckBoxtableColumn restriction by rowdata

Tags: javafx, tablecolumn

I have a checkBoxTableCell field in my tableview and is populated from a data source and I want to disable the checkbox for some rows for which row-data exhibits some conditions.

For example, lets say my data is a Person class object list and 
`if person.exclude=='Y'` then i have to disable the checkbox in that row.

I am trying to do it in the `col_checkBox.setCellFactory(new Callback .....)` I cannot access the person object in this function. And also I tried some other things but without success :( . Any help?

Here is my Code :
column is defined by:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<FVariable, Boolean> col_exclude;
```

I populate table with ;

```
    ObservableList<FVariable> nt = FXCollections.observableArrayList(gd.getInputAtrributes());
    tbl_Attributes.setItems(nt);
```

and then;

```
    col_exclude.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("excluded"));
    //     col_exclude.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(col_exclude));

   final Callback<TableColumn<FVariable, Boolean>,TableCell<FVariable, Boolean>> AllowCellFactory=CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(col_exclude);
    col_exclude.setCellFactory((TableColumn<FVariable, Boolean> param) -> {
        TableCell<FVariable, Boolean> defCell= AllowCellFactory.call(param);


        FVariable p=(FVariable) defCell.getTableRow().getItem();

         if (p.getdType()!='S')
            defCell.disableProperty().set(false);
        else
            defCell.disableProperty().set(true);
        return defCell;
    });
```

Comment: `Person p = (Person) getTableRow().getItem();` should give you access to the object represented in the row from a `TableCell` subclass.

Comment: Nope, it doesnot work. it gives compiletime error and getTableRow is not found.
(Since getTableRow give compile time error I used TableCell instance defCell to overcome the compile time error. But  defcell.gettableRow alwsys returns null and runtime error occurs. I added my code in the question

Answer (score 0):

At Last , I have found a solution inspecting this demo code
http://javafx-demos.googlecode.com/svn-history/r63/trunk/javafx-demos/src/main/java/com/ezest/javafx/demogallery/tableviews/TableViewCheckBoxColumnDemo.java